# R: rJava package fails to load

Tags: r, rjava

I've installed the rJava pack successfully. However, when I run the command `library(rJava)`, I get the following error.

```
 > library(rJava) Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: fun(libname, pkgname)   error: JAVA_HOME
 cannot be determined from the Registry Error: package or namespace
 load failed for ‘rJava’
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running XLConnect as well. It turned out that my instance of R was unable to see the Jave Virtual Machine on my 64 bit Windows computer at work. I simply found the 64 bit version of my `jvm.dll` file in the folder where it lives.

You can just at the path to that .dll file to your `library` or `require()` function and it should undo the madness, although, in my case, I had to update Java completely because it was too old and set this at the beginning of my script to point to the JAVA home.

`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="yourpathhere")`

See if that works.

Comment: Bethany I don't seem to have that file in my computer... Do you know the best place to get it, and where I should install it? Do I need to install a Java compiler?

Comment: If you search and do not have it, probably you will need to install the 64 bit version of Java completely. We had to do this at work. Give it a shot, go to oracle and download and install the most recent stable version for 64 bit.

Comment: I'll do just that. Keep you informed. ;)

Comment: How did it go with the installation? Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi Bethany, afterwards I remember that since my data is also on stata, it would be easier to just use read.dta., instead of opening it through excel.